# How to make a Java Main Menu Loop after using a case

Tags: java, loops, menu, switch-statement

I am pretty dang new to Java, but being familiar with some other programming languages, I know the basic lay out of a lot of it. One thing I am struggling with is looping menus, specifically a main menu.

I have tirelessly researched methods of it, but none seem to apply or work to my program. I'm assuming its something silly and small that I'm missing in my more-so basic program.

Check it below, thanks for any tips.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class basicCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean mainLoop = true;

        int choice;
        do{
            System.out.println("Calculator Main Menu\n");
            System.out.print("1.) Addition \n");
            System.out.print("2.) Subtraction.\n");
            System.out.print("3.) Multiplication.\n");
            System.out.print("4.) Division.\n");
            System.out.print("5.) Generate Random Number.\n");
            System.out.print("6.) Exit\n");
            System.out.print("\nEnter Your Menu Choice: ");

            choice = input.nextInt();


        }

        while(choice >7);

        switch(choice){

        case 1:
            //Definitions
            int adNumf, adNuml, sum;
            System.out.print("Please Enter The First Number: ");
            adNumf = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\nPlease Enter The Second Number: ");
            adNuml = input.nextInt();
            sum = adNumf + adNuml;
            System.out.print("The Sum Of Those Numbers is: " +sum);
            break;

        case 2: 
            int subNum1, subNum2, sum2;
            System.out.println("\nPlease Enter The First Number: ");
            subNum1 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please Enter The Second Number: ");
            subNum2 = input.nextInt();
            sum2 = subNum1 - subNum2;
            System.out.println("The Subtraction Leaves The Number: " +sum2);
            break;

        case 3:
            int multNum1, multNum2, multTotal;

            // Gather Input
            System.out.println("Please Enter The First Number To Multiply: ");
            multNum1 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please Enter The Second Number To Multiply: ");
            multNum2 = input.nextInt();

            // This will Multiply the Numbers
            multTotal = multNum1 * multNum2;

            //Display Final
            System.out.println("The Multiplied Numbers Are: " +multTotal);
            break;

        case 4: 
            //Definitions
            double divNum1, divNum2, divTotal;
            System.out.println("Enter Your Numerator ");
            divNum1 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Your Denominator ");
            divNum2 = input.nextInt();
            if(divNum2 == 0){
                System.out.println("Zero is Not divisable, please select a new denominator: ");
                divNum2 = input.nextInt();
            }
            divTotal = divNum1 / divNum2;
            System.out.println("Your divisor is: " +divTotal);
            break;

        case 5:
            double limL, limH, rand;
            System.out.println("Enter Your Low Limit: ");
            limL = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Your High Limit ");
            limH = input.nextInt();

            //Equation to keep numbers within bounds
            rand = limL + (Math.random() * ((limH - limL) + 1));
            System.out.println("Given Your Limits, the Random Number will be: " +rand);
            break;

        case 6: 
            System.out.println("Exiting Program...");
            System.exit(0);
             break;
        }



        // Bad Menu Option Direct
    if (choice > 6 || choice < 1){
        System.out.println("This is not a valid Menu Option! Please Select Another.");
        do{
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }
        while(choice < 7 );
    }
    // End bad menu option  


    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give whole code(from displaying menu) inside a while loop and give condition as true so that after using a case it will automatically repeat(as you are using 6 to EXIT). And if any invalid input is given for eg:10 the case will go to default section and will execute the code there

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class basicCalc {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean mainLoop = true;

    int choice;
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Calculator Main Menu\n");
        System.out.print("1.) Addition \n");
        System.out.print("2.) Subtraction.\n");
        System.out.print("3.) Multiplication.\n");
        System.out.print("4.) Division.\n");
        System.out.print("5.) Generate Random Number.\n");
        System.out.print("6.) Exit\n");
        System.out.print("\nEnter Your Menu Choice: ");

        choice = input.nextInt();




    switch(choice){

    case 1:
        //Definitions
        int adNumf, adNuml, sum;
        System.out.print("Please Enter The First Number: ");
        adNumf = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\nPlease Enter The Second Number: ");
        adNuml = input.nextInt();
        sum = adNumf + adNuml;
        System.out.print("The Sum Of Those Numbers is: " +sum);
        break;

    case 2: 
        int subNum1, subNum2, sum2;
        System.out.println("\nPlease Enter The First Number: ");
        subNum1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Second Number: ");
        subNum2 = input.nextInt();
        sum2 = subNum1 - subNum2;
        System.out.println("The Subtraction Leaves The Number: " +sum2);
        break;

    case 3:
        int multNum1, multNum2, multTotal;

        // Gather Input
        System.out.println("Please Enter The First Number To Multiply: ");
        multNum1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Second Number To Multiply: ");
        multNum2 = input.nextInt();

        // This will Multiply the Numbers
        multTotal = multNum1 * multNum2;

        //Display Final
        System.out.println("The Multiplied Numbers Are: " +multTotal);
        break;

    case 4: 
        //Definitions
        double divNum1, divNum2, divTotal;
        System.out.println("Enter Your Numerator ");
        divNum1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Denominator ");
        divNum2 = input.nextInt();
        if(divNum2 == 0){
            System.out.println("Zero is Not divisable, please select a new denominator: ");
            divNum2 = input.nextInt();
        }
        divTotal = divNum1 / divNum2;
        System.out.println("Your divisor is: " +divTotal);
        break;

    case 5:
        double limL, limH, rand;
        System.out.println("Enter Your Low Limit: ");
        limL = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Your High Limit ");
        limH = input.nextInt();

        //Equation to keep numbers within bounds
        rand = limL + (Math.random() * ((limH - limL) + 1));
        System.out.println("Given Your Limits, the Random Number will be: " +rand);
        break;

    case 6: 
        System.out.println("Exiting Program...");
        System.exit(0);
         break;
    default :
             System.out.println("This is not a valid Menu Option! Please Select Another");
             break;

    }


    }




    }

   }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Looks pretty renovated, but  could you leave some comments?

Answer (score 4):

You have a general idea of what to do, however you are making your loop ending condition more complicated than it needs to be.  Try a "default" option to catch any input out of the range.  That way you can simplify your ending condition to just "6" (the exit case).  To show simply:

```
do{
  //Menu options
  System.out.print("6.) Exit\n");
  System.out.print("\nEnter Your Menu Choice: ");

  choice = input.nextInt();

  switch(choice){
        //Your cases from 1 to 6.
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid menu choice; try again.");
            break;
   }
}while(choice != 6);
```

Whatever follows default will be called if the choice option is not for any of the cases create in your code.

Comment: I took a few concepts from each program presented, thank you so much everyone, makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

or try thisone

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class basicCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean mainLoop = true;

        int choice;
        do{
            System.out.println("Calculator Main Menu\n");
            System.out.print("1.) Addition \n");
            System.out.print("2.) Subtraction.\n");
            System.out.print("3.) Multiplication.\n");
            System.out.print("4.) Division.\n");
            System.out.print("5.) Generate Random Number.\n");
            System.out.print("6.) Exit\n");
            System.out.print("\nEnter Your Menu Choice: ");
            choice = input.nextInt();




        switch(choice){

        case 1:
            //do something
            break;

        case 2: 
            //do something
            break;

        case 3:
            //do something
            break;

        case 4: 
            //do something
            break;

        case 5:
            //do something
            break;

        case 6: 
            System.out.println("Exiting Program...");
            System.exit(0);
             break;
        default:
        System.out.println(choise + " is not a valid Menu Option! Please Select Another.");

    }while(choice != 6 /*Exit loop when choice is 6*/);



    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your whole execution flow is wrong. You should put the bad menu choice check (in your case the `if`) before the cases. And to have infinite menu loop, just add another `if` that breaks the infinite `while-loop`.

Pseudo code:

```
while(true){
//enter your choice, 8 to exit
  if(choice != valid_range){
//error message
  }
switch(choice){
  case 1: //code
  case 2: //code
  .
  .
  .
  case 7: //code
   if (choice == 8) {
break; //will give flow control to next element after the while statement
   }    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using enhanced switch statements**

I have added a few more things to answers provided here:

1. Enhanced switch statements (in my case I am using Java 15)
2. I have also modularized the code a little bit, therefore I created a function to print the menu options. I could do more but I leave it as is
3. And to avoid the code to crash I added the switch statement inside a `try{}catch()` block

`Note: This can be particularly useful for someone else looking for that same answer`

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class basicCalc {


    private static void printOptions(){
        System.out.println("Calculator Main Menu\n");
        System.out.print("1.) Addition \n");
        System.out.print("2.) Subtraction.\n");
        System.out.print("3.) Multiplication.\n");
        System.out.print("4.) Division.\n");
        System.out.print("5.) Generate Random Number.\n");
        System.out.print("6.) Exit\n");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        boolean mainLoop = true;

        /*Instead of having all your text to print your menu options here
        You put it in a function and call it inside your main method*/
        printOptions();

        int choice;
        while(true){

            System.out.print("\nEnter Your Menu Choice: ");


            /*You also have to add your switch statement in a try catch block
            since you might run into some exception*/
            
            try {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                choice = input.nextInt();
                
                switch (choice) {

                    case 1 -> {
                        //Definitions
                        int adNumf, adNuml, sum;
                        System.out.print("Please Enter The First Number: ");
                        adNumf = input.nextInt();
                        System.out.print("\nPlease Enter The Second Number: ");
                        adNuml = input.nextInt();
                        sum = adNumf + adNuml;
                        System.out.print("The Sum Of Those Numbers is: " + sum);
                    }
                    case 2 -> {
                        int subNum1, subNum2, sum2;
                        System.out.println("\nPlease Enter The First Number: ");
                        subNum1 = input.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Please Enter The Second Number: ");
                        subNum2 = input.nextInt();
                        sum2 = subNum1 - subNum2;
                        System.out.println("The Subtraction Leaves The Number: " + sum2);
                    }

                    case 3 -> {
                        int multNum1, multNum2, multTotal;

                        // Gather Input
                        System.out.println("Please Enter The First Number To Multiply: ");
                        multNum1 = input.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Please Enter The Second Number To Multiply: ");
                        multNum2 = input.nextInt();

                        // This will Multiply the Numbers
                        multTotal = multNum1 * multNum2;

                        //Display Final
                        System.out.println("The Multiplied Numbers Are: " + multTotal);
                    }

                    case 4 -> {
                        //Definitions
                        double divNum1, divNum2, divTotal;
                        System.out.println("Enter Your Numerator ");
                        divNum1 = input.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Enter Your Denominator ");
                        divNum2 = input.nextInt();
                        if (divNum2 == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Zero is Not divisable, please select a new denominator: ");
                            divNum2 = input.nextInt();
                        }
                        divTotal = divNum1 / divNum2;
                        System.out.println("Your divisor is: " + divTotal);
                    }

                    case 5 -> {
                        double limL, limH, rand;
                        System.out.println("Enter Your Low Limit: ");
                        limL = input.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Enter Your High Limit ");
                        limH = input.nextInt();

                        //Equation to keep numbers within bounds
                        rand = limL + (Math.random() * ((limH - limL) + 1));
                        System.out.println("Given Your Limits, the Random Number will be: " + rand);
                    }

                    case 6 -> {
                        System.out.println("Exiting Program...");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    default -> System.out.println("This is not a valid Menu Option! Please Select Another");

                }
            }catch (InputMismatchException ex){
                System.out.println("Invalid input, please provide a number between 1 and 6");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: One way to make that code more readable is to create a Map to store each menu option with its corresponding text and then call that Map inside the function that prints the menu texts